# How to style a select and its option elements and add transitions?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Recently i have been trying to style the `<select>` and    `<option>` with css. But i cannot add transitions.Need some ideas how to style it.  Thanks in Advance...

Here is my HTML

```
<nav class="mobile">
    <span  class="logo"><h1><a href="#">Site Logo</a></h1></span>
    <select>
        <option>Menu</option>
        <option><a href="#">Home</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">Tutorials</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">Freebies</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">Contact</a></option>
        <option><a href="#">About Me</a></option>
    </select>
</nav>
```

Comment: Show your attempts at styling as well.

Comment: What transitions do you want to add?

Comment: Refere to this link: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/29/simple-effects-for-drop-down-lists/ Hope this plugin may help

Comment: I want to add some transitions like opening the menu with increasing its opacity one by one. and i tried to add background to options with gradient but it is supporting gradient background just simple colors.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would add styles to the select tags, pertaining to the transition, what type of transition are you looking for?

You can do `select {}`, `nav > select {}`, `nav select {}`, `.mobile select {}`, or many other ways to target it.

```
.mobile > select {
  width: 190px;
  height: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #2b2b2b;
  background: #eee;
  color: #0c5b78;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

Better Ideas on removing `select`'s default styles and working with them.

[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/dropdown-default-styling/)

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery to style `<select>` or `<option>` is easy , take a look at this

[selectBoxIt](http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/)

Comment: This is a very nice little package but, wouldn't it be even better to make it yourself?